# Swift: Update UITableView.cell.textLabel.text from other class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableViewController`:

```
class MyMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
    }

    func updateFirstMenuRow() {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                println("tableview is \(self.tableView)")
                var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                var rand = arc4random()
                cell!.textLabel!.text = "\(rand)"
                cell!.setNeedsLayout()
                cell!.setNeedsDisplay()
                println("cell is \(cell)")
                println("rand is \(rand)")
                println("textLabel.text is \(cell!.textLabel!.text!)")
            })
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
            }

            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell!.textLabel?.text = "This is the old text"
            case 1:
                cell!.textLabel?.text = "Foo"
            case 2:
                cell!.textLabel?.text = "Bar"
            default:
                cell!.textLabel?.text = "UNDEFINED"
            }

        return cell!

    }

}
```

Note that I have a function `updateFirstMenuRow()` where I'll update the textLabel.text of the first tableView row with a different value (in my text case, a different number).

I need to run `updateFirstMenuRow()` from another class, like below:

```
class MyOtherClass:UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MyMenuTableViewController().updateFirstMenuRow()
    }
    //.....
}
```

It will show all `println` in the console, however it does not update the the cell.textLabel.text with a random number.

In console, I can see that:

- tableView is NOT `nil`
- cell is NOT `nil`
- rand is always a different random number
- textLabel.text returns (strangely enough) the always updated random number (rand)

However, the actual textLabel.text in the `MyMenuTableViewController` is never updated, and stays at it's initial value, `"This is the old text"`.

When I try to run `updateFirstMenuRow()` *within* `UITableViewController`, it will work - meaning, it will update the textLabel.text of the first row in the tableView:

```
class MyMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        updateFirstMenuRow()
    }

}
```

Note that I'm trying to run the update functions from the main thread, as suggested by other stackoverflow questions. However, no success.

I have been struggling with this for several hours now, I'd be glad if anyone can give me some pointers as for why my update function will not properly run - my guess is that it doesn't have "write access" to the `tableView` in `MyMenuTableViewController`. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

**MyMenuTableViewController()**.updateFirstMenuRow()

creates a new instance of `MyMenuTableViewController` - so the method is executed on an instance that isn't on screen.  This is why you see the output of the `println` but no change in the tableview.

You need to pass a reference to the `MyMenuTableViewController` instance to the `MyOtherClass` instance.  You need to add a property to `MyOtherClass` to hold the reference -

```
menuTableViewController:MyMenuTableViewController?
```

You don't show how you get from one to the other, but, for example if it was via a segue you would use the following -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)  {
    if (segue.identifier == "someIdentifier") {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as MyOtherClass
        destinationVC.menuTableViewController = self
    }
}
```

Then in your `MyOtherClass` you can say -

```
if (self.menuTableViewController != nil) {
    self.menuTableViewController!.updateFirstMenuRow()
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, and first of all thanks for your answer. I am in fact using a delegate, which is triggered in the `MyOtherClass`, to "forward" the command to update the textLabel.text - however, I managed to get the correct reference. Before, I was using `MyMenuTableViewController()` twice, but now I am using `var menuTableViewController:MyMenuTableViewController?`, then I set the value once with `self.menuTableViewController = MyMenuTableViewController()` and then subsequently I use `menuTableViewController!` or `menuTableViewController!.updateFirstMenuRow()`, so I always update the "same" tableView

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem thanks to Paul's answer.

I am in fact using a delegate, which is triggered in the `MyOtherClass`, to "forward" the command to update the textLabel.text - however, I managed to get the correct reference.

Before, I was using `MyMenuTableViewController()` twice

Now I am using `var menuTableViewController:MyMenuTableViewController?`, then I set the value once with `self.menuTableViewController = MyMenuTableViewController()` and then subsequently I use `menuTableViewController!` or `menuTableViewController!.updateFirstMenuRow()`, so I always update the tableView in the "same" instance of `MyMenuTableViewController`.